# Find a person that is referenced in a document

Tags: javascript, database, node.js, postgresql, full-text-search

**Lets say, I have:**

- a *database* with **13000 person entries** , including `first name, name, birthday, street, zip code, city`
- a *long text* that includes the **personal data of one specific person**. Because it was processesed by OCR it could contain `spelling errors`

**Here you can read the text:**

```
  Harry Potter, born 25.03.1995, resident at Jahnstreet 43, London is a series of seven fantasy novels written by British author J. K. Rowling. The series chronicles the adventures of a young wizard, Harry Potter, the titular character, and his friends Ronald Weasley and Hermione Granger, all of whom are students at Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry. The main story arc concerns Harry's quest to defeat the Dark wizard Lord Voldemort, who aims to become immortal, conquer the wizarding world, subjugate non-magical people, and destroy all those who stand in his way, especially Harry Potter. Since the release of the first novel, Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, on 30 June 1997, the books have gained immense popularity, critical acclaim and commercial success worldwide.[2] The series has also had some share of criticism, including concern about the increasingly dark tone as the series progressed. As of May 2015, the books have sold more than 450 million copies worldwide, making the series the best-selling book series in history, and have been translated into 73 languages.[3][4] The last four books consecutively set records as the fastest-selling books in history, with the final installment selling roughly 11 million copies in the United States within the first 24 hours of its release. A series of many genres, including fantasy, coming of age and the British school story (with elements of mystery, thriller, adventureand romance), it has many cultural meanings and references.[5] According to Rowling, the main theme is death.[6] There are also many other themes in the series, such as prejudice and corruption.[7]
```

---

Now **I want to find the Person in the database that is referenced in the document**

---

I have different ideas on how to do that. But I do not know which one brings the best results? **Which way would you prefer? recommend?** Thanks

1. I split the text in an array, and go through each `birthday` in the database and search it with javascripts `text.search('25.03.1995')` when there is a hit, I go through the next field for eg. `text.searc('Harry')`. If there are several hits, I found the right record.

   - *pros*: Easy to implement, No need for database commands, pure javascript
   - *cons*: If OCR made an error and read for eg. `Harly` instead of `Harry` I can't identfiy it. The same happens if the date formats are different
2. First I index the text with the help of a database. Next I take a similar approach like in the first example. And go through each column in the database but now with Database `CONTAINS`

   - *pros:* Faster, Better Results?
   - *cons:* I need a good Full-Text-Search Database
3. I split the text and search for each single world in the database columns with  sql - `LIKE`

   - *pros:* I don't have to index the file, Like better than Contains?
   - *cons:* Not as fast as an text index?

**Thanks for your help in this matter**

Comment: Maybe some sort of fuzzy search can help you overcome the OCR errors. Try this one for example - http://glench.github.io/fuzzyset.js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think because of OCR errors you will have to sometimes sort through multiple possible matches and 13000 entries doesn't require a lot of memory.  So it might be easier to just use the first approach and do it entirely in JS.  Either way you have to try to parse the CSV.

It depends on how bad the OCR is I suppose.  If it is bad the full text indexing might help.

You might also try using something like string-distance from the `natural` module in npm.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok. I added another idea I just had.